# Discord.py Rewrite Custom Help Embed Sort commands by Cog

Tags: discord.py

Ok so I'm working on one of my older bots and am attempting to rewrite my custom help command to be a bit less manual. However, I'm not sure how to get this working as intended.

My issues are as follows:

1. It keeps responding with the `I can't send embeds` exception
2. There's no error showing up in the console logs

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Here is my custom Help command.

```
    @commands.command(name="help", aliases=["Help", "H", "h"])
    @commands.has_permissions(add_reactions=True, embed_links=True)
    async def help(self, ctx, *cog):
        """Gets all cogs and commands.
        Alt     : h, H, Help
        Usage   : [h]elp <cog or command>"""
        try:
            if not cog:
                """Cog listing.  What more?"""
                embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_gold(), 
                title='Cog Listing and Uncatergorized Commands',
                description=f'Use `{prefix}help <cog>` to find out more about them!\nNote: The Cog Name Must Be in Title Case, Just Like this Sentence.',
                timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
                embed.set_author(name=self.client.user.name, icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                cogs_desc = ''
                for x in self.client.cogs:
                    cogs_desc += ('{} - {}'.format(x, self.client.cogs[x].__doc__) + '\n')
                embed.add_field(name='Cogs', value=cogs_desc[0:len(cogs_desc) - 1], inline=False)
                cmds_desc = ''
                for y in self.client.walk_commands():
                    if not y.cog_name and not y.hidden:
                        cmds_desc += ('{} - {}'.format(y.name, y.help) + '\n')
                embed.add_field(name='Uncatergorized Commands', value=cmds_desc[0:len(cmds_desc) - 1], inline=False)
                await ctx.send('', embed=embed)
            else:
                """Helps me remind you if you pass too many args."""
                if len(cog) > 1:
                    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_red(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
                    embed.set_author(name="Command Failed", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                    embed.add_field(name="Error", value="Too many cogs", inline=False)
                    await ctx.send('', embed=embed)
                else:
                    """Command listing within a cog."""
                    found = False
                    for x in self.client.cogs:
                        for y in cog:
                            if x == y:
                                embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_gold(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, title=cog[0] + ' Command Listing', description=self.client.cogs[cog[0]].__doc__)
                                for c in self.client.get_cog(y).get_commands():
                                    if not c.hidden:
                                        embed.add_field(name=c.name, value=c.help, inline=False)
                                found = True
                    if not found:
                        """Reminds you if that cog doesn't exist."""
                        embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_red(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
                        embed.set_author(name="Command Failed", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
                        embed.add_field(name="Error", value='Can not use "' + cog[0] + '"?', inline=False)
                    else:
                        await ctx.send('', embed=embed)
        except:
            await ctx.send("I can't send embeds.")
```

I'm using `discord.py-rewrite` if it helps.

---EDIT---

I gave up on the above code due to countless issues with it. And went for the following code. I'd still like it to be less manual but for now this one actually posts.

````
    @commands.command(name="Help", aliases=["help", "h", "H"])
    async def _help(self, ctx):
        """Displays all available commands"""
        msg = ctx.message
        await msg.delete()
        contents = [
            f"```css\nAdministrator Commands\n\nBroadcast:  [B]roadcast <message>\nPurge:      [p]urge <1-100>\nBan:        [B]an <user> [reason]\nUnban:      [U]nban <user>\nKick:       [K]ick <user> [reason]\n\nOptional arguments are represented with []\nRequired arguments are represented with <>\nDo not include the [] or <> flags in the command\n ```",
            f"```css\nModerator Commands!\n\nAnnounce:   [ann]ounce <message>\nClean:      [C]lean <1-100>\n\nOptional arguments are represented with []\nRequired arguments are represented with <>\nDo not include the [] or <> flags in the command\n ```",
            f"```css\nFun Commands\n\nGiphy:      [ ] < >\nTenor:      [ ] < >\n\nOptional arguments are represented with []\nRequired arguments are represented with <>\nDo not include the [] or <> flags in the command\n ```",
            f"```css\nUtility Commands\n\nPing:       ping\nJoined:     [J]oined [user]\nTopRole:   [top]role [user]\nPerms:      perms [user]\nHelp:       [H]elp [command]\n\nOptional arguments are represented with []\nRequired arguments are represented with <>\nDo not include the [] or <> flags in the command\n ```"
            ]
        pages = 4
        cur_page = 1
        message = await ctx.send(f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")
        # getting the message object for editing and reacting

        await message.add_reaction("◀️")
        await message.add_reaction("▶️")

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["◀️", "▶️"]
            # This makes sure nobody except the command sender can interact with the "menu"

        while True:
            try:
                reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)
                # waiting for a reaction to be added - times out after x seconds, 60 in this
                # example

                if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️" and cur_page != pages:
                    cur_page += 1
                    await message.edit(content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")
                    await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

                elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️" and cur_page > 1:
                    cur_page -= 1
                    await message.edit(content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")
                    await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
                    # removes reactions if the user tries to go forward on the last page or
                    # backwards on the first page
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await message.delete()
                break
                # ending the loop if user doesn't react after x seconds

    @_help.error
    async def _help_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            guild = ctx.guild
            embed = discord.Embed(
                color=discord.Color.dark_red(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name="Command Failed",
                             icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Missing Required arguments",
                            value="Please pass in all required arguments.", inline=False)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
            await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="⚠️️")
            await ctx.message.author.send(embed=embed)
            print("[ERROR] Missing Required Arguments")

        elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            guild = ctx.guild
            embed = discord.Embed(
                color=discord.Color.dark_red(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name="Access denied",
                             icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Insufficient Permissions",
                            value="You do not have permission to use this command.", inline=False)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.client.user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{guild.name}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
            await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="")
            await ctx.message.author.send(embed=embed)
            print("[ERROR] Insufficient Permissions")
````

But yes, if anyone knows how to make it so the commands are read from the cogs instead of manually typed into the help command's response any tips would be very helpful.

Comment: Remove the try...except so that you can see the error.

Comment: yo sorry, I gave up on this command and just completely rebuilt it. Unfortunately my new one is manual but it still looks miles better than the built in help command. i'll update my post with what I ended up sticking to.